# Can a Java class have a method that works on multiple of its objects?

Tags: java, oop

I have a simple task to code an immutable class Size with a single int field s. One of the class operations is "plus" that "adds two Size objects with the obvious result". The way I am reading it, I am supposed to use the method of an object of class Size to add itself to another object of class Size. I find it strange that an object's method would be to take itself and another instance of the same class as parameters. Is this normal? Or am I reading the question incorrectly?

Comment: the description says: "adds two Size objects with the obvious result" but it can be interpreted as either 1) two size objects in parameter (you could probably make it a static method) ```add(s1, s2);``` 2) one size object in the parameter (non-static) but it returns ```this.s + secondObj.s;```. for example: ```s1.add(s2);```

Comment: I apologize, I am somewhat unfamiliar with Java. To call the static method, would it be something like s1.add(s1, s2);?

Comment: nope, because its a static method, you can just call it directly without having to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is normal and not too uncommon behavior. Look at the BigInteger class as an example of just this. Its [add method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)) does exactly what you are trying to do -- it returns a *new* immutable BigInteger instance that is the sum of the two values, the current value plus the parameter's value.